# Why is benzoic acid a stronger acid than acetic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Why is benzoic acid ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 4.20$) a stronger acid than acetic acid ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 4.76$), even though the conjugate base in case of benzoic acid is destabilized due to electron donation through resonance. Whereas there is nothing of that sort operating in acetic acid; only inductive and hyperconjugative electron donation.

Comment: The answer lies in the resonance energy of various resonance structures of both the carbanions (formed after donating H+).

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7309/resonance-of-benzoic-acid

Comment: Among various types of resonance effects equivalent Resonance makes the most stable molecules. Here the resonance with benzene ring causes the carboxylate ion to lose its precious equivalent Resonance and thus decrease its acidity.

Comment: @SujithSizon You're second comment is wrong and vide your first comment - we have oxoanions, not carbanions here.

Comment: @Mithoron hmm.. but isn't stability of oxanions proportional to carbanion stability here? Also isn't equivalent resonance in $\ce{COO-}$ the reason for the higher energy of separate resonance structures. Don't we use the same fact for proving that acidity: H-COOH > Ph-COOH?

Comment: @Mithoron the questions that you have cited are in no way same as what I had asked. Interestingly the two questions in the links even contradict each other.

Comment: Aromatic ring is inductive acceptor and mesomeric donor - together it makes benzoic acid stronger then  acetic which is only inductive donor. @SujithSizon I don't get your point

Comment: @Mithoron you cannot probably say that aromatic ring is inductive acceptor  straight away. What if we add a fluorine group to it ?

Comment: @Mithoron When we try to show that formic acid is more acidic than benzoic acid, all these points regarding Inductive and Mesomeric effect are immediately flawed. Sooner or later Abhirikshma will face the same situation, thats why i was trying to give him hint regarding resonance energies.

Comment: I found a solution on YouTube

Comment: https://youtu.be/wH3dVLxxoYs     (in HINDI)

Answer (score 6):

It is all about the electron withdrawing/ donating nature of the acid's functional groups.  The more electron withdrawing the group, the stronger the acid will be.  The more electron donating the weaker the acid will be.  A phenyl ring is electron withdrawing, while a methyl group is electron donating.  I don't know why resonance would destabilize an organic molecule or ion.  if you are referring to the carboxylate donating electrons to the phenyl ring, I don't see how this could be possible and not violate the octet rule.

Comment: The phenyl ring is donating electron to the carboxylic acid group through resonance, that is what I am talking about.

Comment: The aromatic ring is so thermodynaically stable that the phenyl ring donating electrons to the carboxylate is not a major resonace structure. Though it is enough to dictate meta directed electrophilic aromatic substitution.

Comment: How is that the ortho effect in substituted benzoic acids increase the acidic strength ?

Comment: please elaborate.

Comment: When we add a bulky substituent at the ortho position it throws the carboxylic acid group out of plane and thus successfully inhibits the phenyl ring from donating electron through resonance, and increases the acidic strength.

Comment: @Abhirikshma http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/ortho-effect-in-substituted-aromatic-acids-and-bases Please refrain fro  prolonged discussions in comments. There's [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) for that

Comment: @A.K.  I agree that because of the stability due to aromaticity, phenyl ring donating electrons to the carboxylate is not a major resonance structure and that electron withdrawing nature of phenyl group stabilizes the negative charge, but in that case how will we explain that formic acid(pKa=3.751) is more acidic than benzoic acid(pka=4.204). Before reading your comment, I believed that it was because of the destabilization caused by phenyl ring to caboxylate. But now how to explain it?

Comment: OP is on the point, to satisfy one condition(benzoic acid>acetic acid or formic acid>benzoic acid)  other will contradict instantly